# Combining tabularray and aligned environment

Tags: amsmath, mathtools, tabularray

I am trying to get the following to work

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\tn}[1]{\textnormal{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Utevolv}{\ensuremath{\hat{\mathcal{U}}}}
\newcommand*{\imag}{\mathrm{i}}

% ------------ braket --------------
% mathtools als Voraussetzung.
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\bra{\langle}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ket{\lvert}{\rangle}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braketzw[2]{\langle}{\rangle}%
{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braketdr[3]{\langle}{\rangle}%
{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{%
    colspec = {@{}Q[t]Q[t]@{}},%
    column{2} = {mode=dmath}
    }
    General ansatz:    & \ket{\Psi(t)} = \sum_n c_n(t) \ket{n} \\                                                                                                                            \\
    Amplitude $c_k(t)$ & \begin{aligned} %
                             c_k(t) = \braketzw{k}{\Psi(t)} & = \braketdr{k}{\Utevolv(t,t_0)}{\Psi(t_0)}                                                        \\
                                                            & = \braketdr{k}{\Utevolv_0(t,t_0)\, \Utevolv_\tn{I}(t,t_0)}{\Psi(t_0)}                             \\
                                                            & = \exp \left[ - \frac{\imag E_k t}{\hbar} \right] \braketdr{k}{\Utevolv_\tn{I}(t,t_0)}{\Psi(t_0)}
                         \end{aligned} \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Wanted output:
[image]

I was hoping to get a top-aligned column, but the `aligned` environment and the `t` for `tabularray` seem to be not compatible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you already try `\begin{aligned}[t]`?

Comment: `\begin{aligned}[t]`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer and @leandriis Thank you very much! This fixed the problem… I did not know that `aligned` takes an optinal argument with `[t]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @UlrikeFischer and @leandriis.

I was not aware of the fact, that the `aligned` environment provides an **optional argument** for alignment of the env itself.

Fixed it with:

```
... \begin{aligned}[t] ...
```

Fully working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\tn}[1]{\textnormal{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Utevolv}{\ensuremath{\hat{\mathcal{U}}}}
\newcommand*{\imag}{\mathrm{i}}

% ------------ braket --------------
% mathtools als Voraussetzung.
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\bra{\langle}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ket{\lvert}{\rangle}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braketzw[2]{\langle}{\rangle}%
{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braketdr[3]{\langle}{\rangle}%
{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{%
    colspec = {@{}Q[t]Q[t]@{}},%
    column{2} = {mode=dmath}
    }
    General ansatz:    & \ket{\Psi(t)} = \sum_n c_n(t) \ket{n} \\                                                                                                                            \\
    Amplitude $c_k(t)$ & \begin{aligned}[t] %
                             c_k(t) = \braketzw{k}{\Psi(t)} & = \braketdr{k}{\Utevolv(t,t_0)}{\Psi(t_0)}                                                        \\
                                                            & = \braketdr{k}{\Utevolv_0(t,t_0)\, \Utevolv_\tn{I}(t,t_0)}{\Psi(t_0)}                             \\
                                                            & = \exp \left[ - \frac{\imag E_k t}{\hbar} \right] \braketdr{k}{\Utevolv_\tn{I}(t,t_0)}{\Psi(t_0)}
                         \end{aligned} \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```